# REST API filtering/search on a parent resource

Tags: rest, api, json-api

Suppose I have a store such as Amazon that sells a variety of products such as **computers** and **paintings**. They are quite different from each other and have their own set of fields and logic.

In addition to the typical CRUD, I need to design a JSON API that allows me to:

A. Fetch an ungrouped list of **paintings** and **computers**. For example: `[computer, painting, painting, computer, ...]` ordered by date published (so with filtering capability).

B. Fetch only paintings

C. Fetch only computers

The RESTful approach will typically be something like: `/api/paintings` and `api/computers` which works really well for segregated results.

But my main concern is **operation A** - getting an ungrouped list of paintings and products sorted by date published. The way I see it, there are three approaches:

1) Create a new standalone resource called `products` such as `/api/products` which will have filtering capability and continue to use `/api/resource` for specific CRUD operations.

2) Create a parent `products` resource which will be used for filtering operations. So I can do something like `/products?order_by=published_date` And for more specific resources I can do something like `/products/paintings` or `/products/computers`

3) Do not have a resource for **paintings** or **computers**. Instead have one for a generic `product`. I will then have most logic in the api layer and reduce the complexity of the client.

I am leaning towards approach #3 but wanted to get feedback prior to implementing since this will be a core feature of the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always taken the approach the your API Layer should match your object modeling.  So, the answer to your question would be it depends on the source data.  Well, the source data after it's object modeling.

If you have an object model for Computer and for Printer, they should be resources like you've said.  Do they share any data/functions?  If so, you should have an object model for that, too, perhaps: Product.  Then Computer and Printer extend the Product class.

With that in mind, design the API layer to mirror it.  Since Computer and Printer both extend Product.  Product as a parent of the Computer and Printer resources make sense.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I would go for approach #3 and query the API with type of product if you search for it.

```
/products?type=computers&order_by=date
```

Comment: I'd recommend this method, too, if the Type (Computer-ness or Painting-ness) of a Product was simply an attribute.  In that case, the the object model would contain only one class: Product.  However, as Kobe explained, a Computer and a Painting are distinctly different objects and each have their own attributes and functions.  Thus, there are three classes in the object model: Computer, Painting, and Product.  The former two of which extend the latter.  Writing the API layer to mirror the object model creates easier future extension/modification and mains maintaining code easier.

Comment: @Tim I may be missing something but isn't that exactly mirrored in approach #3?

Comment: yes, it was mirrored in approach #3.  The question asked "which one of these should I use?"  My answer was "it depends on your object models." which, in this case, was #3 but "#3" was not my answer.